# How to render Alert Component conditionally in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to customize the Alert Component. For that in the render() method I am 
wrapping  Alert inside the AlerBoxContainer class (that is placed in alertbox-container.tsx file) . I am rendering it by toggling using a prop.

**Approach -1** : By directly returning the Alert component if the condition is true or returning null if condition is false.

This is in alertbox-container.tsx file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Alert} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { State } from "../../../../store/reducer";
import * as constants from "../../constants";
import * as selectors from "../../selectors";
import { AlertBox, AlertBoxContainerProps } from "./alertbox";

interface AlertBoxState {
    showAlert: boolean;
    blurred: boolean;
    appState: any;
}

class AlertBoxContainer extends React.Component<AlertBoxContainerProps, AlertBoxState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
}

render() {
    return this.props.isAlertVisible ?
        Alert.alert(constants.ALERT_HEADER, constants.ALERT_MESSAGE, [
            { text: constants.CANCEL_TEXT, onPress: () => this.props.onCancel() },
            { text: constants.EXIT_TEXT, onPress: () => this.props.onExit() }
        ])
        :  null;
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State): AlertBoxContainerProps => ({
    isAlertVisible: selectors.getIsAlertVisible(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<core.features.workplace.Action>): AlertBoxContainerProps => ({
    toggleAlertVisible: () => dispatch(core.features.workplace.toggleAlertVisible())
});

export default connect<any, AlertBoxContainerProps, AlertBoxContainerProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AlertBoxContainer);
```

When I tried the above code I got the error :

Property 'render' in type 'AlertBoxContainer' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Component'.
  Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => ReactNode'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2416)

I also tried in the following way :

**Aprroach - 2:**

in alertbox-container.tsx :

```
 render() {
return (
    <AlertBox
        isAlertVisible={this.props.isAlertVisible}
        onCancel={this.props.onCancel}
        onExit={this.props.onExit}
    />
);
}
```

In alertbox.tsx file :

```
import { Alert, View } from "react-native";
import * as constants from "../../constants";
export interface AlertBoxContainerProps {
    isAlertVisible?: boolean;
    toggleAlertVisible?: () => any;
    navigation?: any;
    hardwareBackPress?: () => any;
    onExit?: () => any;
    onCancel?: () => any;
}

export const AlertBox = (props: AlertBoxContainerProps) => {
    return props.isAlertVisible
    ? (
        Alert.alert(constants.ALERT_HEADER, constants.ALERT_MESSAGE, [
            { text: constants.CANCEL_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onCancel() },
            { text: constants.EXIT_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onExit() }
        ])
    )
    : null; 
};
```

When I tried this code I got the error : " JSX element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.ts(2605) "

How can I get rid of these errors and render the alert box?

When I tried with the second approach and by modifying the code I am able to render the Alert, with the following code :

**Approach -3 :**

In alertbox.tsx :

```
export const AlertBox = (props: AlertBoxContainerProps) => {
return (
    <View>
        {}
        {props.isAlertVisible
            ? Alert.alert(constants.ALERT_HEADER, constants.ALERT_MESSAGE, [
                  { text: constants.CANCEL_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onCancel() },
                  { text: constants.EXIT_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onExit() }
              ])
            : null}
    </View>
);
```

};

But the code is with the weird syntax where in the view I need to place empty '{ }' other wise I get the error :

" Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(725, 39): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly>' " .

Answer (score 2):

This issue is that `Alert.alert()` is not a Component, it’s a function (calling the `alert()` method). The `render` function must be passed a `Component`, so that is why you are getting the errors.

`Alert.alert()` is easy to use and handy. It doesn’t have to be in the `render` method at all to work, in fact it doesn’t even need to be in a `Component` to work. All you need to do is call it when you want it to come up. For example, here is how you could bring up an alert at the press of a button:

```
class Example extends Component<*, *> {
  
  callAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      “Alert title”,
      “Alert explanation”,
      [
        {
          text: “Yes”,
          onPress: () => console.log(“Yes pressed”),
        },
        {
          text: “No”,
          onPress: () => console.log('No Pressed'),
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.callAlert}>
        <Text>
          Alert Button
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

In your case, whenever you toggle your prop, call the alert and everything should be peachy!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <View>
    {}
    {props.isAlertVisible
        && Alert.alert(constants.ALERT_HEADER, constants.ALERT_MESSAGE, [
              { text: constants.CANCEL_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onCancel() },
              { text: constants.EXIT_TEXT, onPress: () => props.onExit() }
          ])
        }
</View>
```

**If null is creating the issue then you could do a short-circuit**
Hope it helps !

Comment: please see the last approach I tried ...it is same as you suggested . There I am not facing any issues with null and I am able to render the Alert box but I want to remove the empty " {} " symbol in the <view> component as it is syntactically weird.